# Resources to Write ANSI C++ Code

Tags: c++, resources, c++98

The last time I heavily used C++ was years ago, and it was strictly done on the Windows platform.  Specifically, I used Microsoft Visual Studio as my IDE and developed some habitual patterns to use Microsoft's C++ version.  For example, I used **void main()** instead of the standard **int main()**.

Now, I am taking a class where it is required to develop programs to be ANSI C++ compliant and the code will be compiled using g++.  I quickly learned that **system ( "PAUSE" )** does not work in g++ and is probably a Microsoft thing.

Does anyone know of any good resources ( sites, tutorials, books ) where I can learn what more to be better ANSI C++ complaint?

Thank you.

Comment: The system() function is standard.  It is the "pause" command that is not. The function merely issues commands to the system shell.

Comment: Try this more portable *pause* idiom:  `std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');`.  It waits until a newline is entered.

Comment: Waiting for newline will often fail to stop the program especially in beginners' programs that use std::cin >> value to read something, so that the newline that follows the input is left unread. Normally it is better to only read std::cin by std::getline function, so that the input is actually read a line at a time. This avoids having to understand how the line-buffered input from the OS actually works (why nothing can be read until the user presses enter, except on some systems or with some terminal settings, or if the input is flushed for some reason).

Comment: A better way for waiting is to enable "keep window open after program termination" or some similar setting in project settings of the IDE. Most (if not all) IDEs offer such a setting.

Comment: Is there such a standard, ANSI C++? I'm aware only of ANSI C and ISO C++.

Comment: I should have been clearer above.  I am aware of "system" being standard but as Clifford mentioned not the "PAUSE" parameter.  I will be more clearer in my posts.

Comment: @Checkers: Technically yes. It's entirely identical apart from the copyright notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend these two:

- [comp.lang.c++](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/topics) Usenet newsgroup.  If you can get hold of a good Usenet service provider, and use a news reader, you should be able to get rid of the spam.  I use [eternal-september.org](http://www.eternal-september.org/), and like it a lot.
- Read the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/).  It has a lot of great information.

Granted, they both are not terribly great if you want a tutorial introduction to C++, but looks like you already know some C++, and need to learn more, and correct bad habits.  From my personal experience, the above two are highly useful in doing exactly that.

About `comp.lang.c++`, make sure you fully read their FAQ and lurk there a while before posting.  The same applies to stackoverflow of course, although lurking may not be necessary here.

Using `g++`, compile your programs with `g++ -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++`, and make sure you understand all the warnings.  I use:

```
g++ -Wextra -Wall -Weffc++ -ansi -pedantic -Woverloaded-virtual \
-Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith
```

Comment: I would highly recommend avoiding comp.lang.c++ (and I'm still one of it's all-time top 10 posters) - you are much better off asking C++ questions here. If you want to use Usenet, go to http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/topics

Comment: @Neil: Why avoid `comp.lang.c++`?

Comment: Spam (which you can avoid to a certain extent using a newsreader, as you said), trolls (which you can't) and some not very bright people. The moderated group is much better.

Comment: Yes. The same is true about `comp.lang.c` for example.  But after reading the newsgroup for a while, you learn whose advice to ignore, and who know what they're saying.  `comp.lang.c++` has more interesting discussion, at the expense of needing more weeding.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using g++, then compile with the -pedantic and -std=c++98 flags.  The only standard for ANSI C++ is really the ISO Standard document, which cannot be recommended to a beginner. You are mistaken about system("PAUSE"), by the way - system() is part of ANSI C++ - it's parameter is not standardised, however.

Answer (score 1):

Most C++ books will be platform agnostic (of course unless they are made specifically for Visual C++). Here are some [good books](http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/fncpp/Resources#books) that are recommended by the pros on ##C++

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of good tutorials gcc, has a flag that will make sure the code is ANSI C compliant too, `gcc -ansi -Wall -fsyntax-only -pedantic`

```
* Wall - turn on all errors
* ansi - use strict ANSI C specification
* fsyntax-only - only checks syntax
* pedantic - reject violations
```

Per, comments In addition you can use
    * -Wextra to turn on a few extra warnings,

*update* thanks for update on capitalization., and mention of -pedantic

Comment: you've got the capitalization wrong, it's actually `-Wall`.  also, the gcc/g++ manpage says *In C++ mode, remove GNU extensions that conflict with ISO C++. [...] The `-ansi` option does not cause non‐ISO programs to be rejected gratuitously.  For that, `-pedantic` is required in addition to -ansi.*

Answer (score 1):

GCC will do a good job of telling you when your code is not ISO C++ compliant (not that it is an ISO standard, not an ANSI standard).  Set the warning options -Werror -Wall, and simply fix all warnings; you soon get out of non-compliant habits and ger fewer and fewer warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of gcc fans.

The important flags to compile with under Visual Studio to be as strict as possible are:

```
cl /Za /W4 ...rest of command...
```

/Za disables Microsoft specific extensions and /W4 is the highest warning level (except /Wall, which complains about ridiculous things).

I'd also recommend you use a modern version of Visual Studio - old versions (VC6) were ridiculously non-conformant, and Microsoft officially pretends they never existed at this point.

Comment: I currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, and based on all these comments installed gcc as well.  I have never heard of this compiler before.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend.

websites:

- http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/
- http://cppreference.com
- boost.org

books:

- effective C++
- effective stl
- modern c++ design
- template metaprogramming

talking / listening to experts and understanding what they have to say and why.

Answer (score 0):

C++ Primer (4th Ed) appears to be the best beginner book these days as it takes a modern approach and teaches all the important parts of the language. Accelerated C++ is another book often recommended by professionals and it serves as a good introduction, but I wouldn't recommend buying it anymore because C++ Primer nicely replaces it and covers the language better.

Note: C++ Primer Plus (which is a rather bad book) has nothing to do with C++ Primer.

Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language always needs to be mentioned, of course, because it is written by the father of the language. Many people find it enlightening, but I personally would not recommend it for learning the language.

All the books I mentioned only describe the ISO standard with no non-standard extensions. The programs in these books should work with any C++ compiler.

Comment: C++ Primer is by Lippman & Lajoie, while Accelerated C++ is by Koenig & Moo. Neither makes the other "largely useless".

Comment: The authors of the 4th edition are Lippman, Lajoie and Moo, and the new edition is very different from the 3rd edition. While AC++ is a good introduction, with a modern approach, it only covers a very small portion of the language. C++ Primer also takes that same modern approach (thanks to Moo, I must assume). Since C++ Primer is also far more complete, I see no reason in buying AC++ anymore. The answer edited (after your comment) to clarify what I meant.

Comment: This review at Amazon clarifies the issue: http://www.amazon.com/review/RLTC8B1UR0LRQ/ref=cm_cr_pr_viewpnt#RLTC8B1UR0LRQ
Andrew Koenig, the other author of AC++, also comments on this review: http://www.amazon.com/review/R2V99WR8ZNX4NM/ref=cm_cr_pr_viewpnt#R2V99WR8ZNX4NM
(the two reviews linked are the highest approved positive and negative reviews of the book)

Answer (score 0):

I like visiting www.cplusplus.com whenever I have a doubt, specially about the standard C++ library.